# Can't write xpath expression to get to the image link

Tags: xpath

A blank class just mess my expression up. Here is the html elements for the image link:

```
<div data-index="0" style="width: 300px; left: 0px; transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"><img alt="" class="" src="https://images.craigslist.org/00G0G_40m7DOu6DO3_300x300.jpg"></div>
```

Here is what i tried with:

```
//div/img/@src
```

Comment: The XPath looks good. The error is not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks sir, Tomalak for your response. Can't get any idea how to locate the image link.

Answer (score 0):

//div/img[@class='abc']/@src

try giving your class a name and use the xpath expression

Comment: Thanks Vikram Saini for your reply. But, still the same as I was getting applying mine.

Comment: then you can try //div/img[@src]

Answer (score 0):

```
In [27]: text = """ <div data-index="0" style="width: 300px; left: 0px; transiti
...: on-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"><img alt="" class=""
...:  src="https://images.craigslist.org/00G0G_40m7DOu6DO3_300x300.jpg"></di
...: v>"""

In [28]: from scrapy.selector import Selector
In [29]: sel = Selector(text=text)
In [30]: sel.xpath('//img[@class=""]/@src').extract()
Out[31]: ['https://images.craigslist.org/00G0G_40m7DOu6DO3_300x300.jpg']
```